# Writing from .csv to txt file but with differing space patterns between the columns

Tags: vba, csv, export-to-text

I have a .csv file with 4 columns.  I would like to place my excel data into a txt file, however, I want to have different spacing options between the columns one they are on the txt file.

Example - if row 1 with four columns is [column a = 2 column b = 3, column c = 4, and column d = 5], the output in the text file will be:

```
2       3    4              5
```

There is a tab between the 2 and 3, four spaces between the 3 and 4, and 14 spaces between the 4 and 5.  This is quite random, but formatting is due to previous files created.

I wrote the following code per a tutorial, but am not sure how to manipulate it to get differerent spacing for each line.

```
Sub excelToTxt()

Dim FilePath As String
Dim CellData As String
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

CellData = vbTab

FilePath = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\test.txt"

Open FilePath For Output As #2
For i = 1 To LastRow

For j = 1 To LastCol

    If j = LastCol Then
        CellData = CellData + Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value)
    Else
        CellData = Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value) + CellData
    End If

Next j

Write #2, CellData
CellData = vbTab

Next i

Close #2


End
```

Is anyone able to help with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
Dim spacing As Variant

Select Case Cells(i, j).Column
    Case 1: spacing = vbTab
    Case 2: spacing = Space(4) - Len(Cells(i, j).Value)
    Case 3: spacing = Space(14) - Len(Cells(i, j).Value)
End Select

Write #2, Cells(i, j).Value & spacing
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to modify the section where you are writing the values out.  Check what column you are writing out and add the value you need between the columns.

Something like this.

```
    For j = 1 To LastCol

        If j = LastCol Then
            CellData = CellData + Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value)
        Elseif j = 1 Then
            CellData = Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value) + CellData
        Elseif j = 2 Then
            CellData = Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value) + vbTab
        Elseif j = 3 Then
            CellData = Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value) + "    "
        Elseif j = 4 Then
            CellData = Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value) + "         "
        Elseif j = 5 Then
            CellData = Trim(ActiveCell(i, j).Value) + "  "
        End If

    Next j

    Write #2, CellData
    CellData = vbTab
```

Comment: If you think you've found a duplicate question please flag it as such rather than posting duplicate answers. If it's not a duplicate then **tailor your answer to the specifics of the question,**